# Selenium + VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy tratando de automatizar un proceso de mi empresa, y con IE lo puedo hacer de manera fácil ya que excel incorpora una librería para poder hacer este proceso, pero cuando intento hacer lo mismo con la pagina que necesito cargar al resolver el catcha me reinicia o me actualizar la pagina al mandarle el click al botón para continuar, cuando hago el mismo proceso con chrome no me ocurre eso, con IE jalo la información por las etiquetas peor eso lo puedo hacer gracias a la librería que tiene incorporada el VBA excel.
Leyendo por todos lados encontré una herramienta que se llama Selenium con la cual puedo hacer lo mismo que con IE, ya la instale importe la librería a excel, pero cuando lo ejecuto me parece el siguiente error.

[image: Error de Selenium]
Ya descargue el chromedriver para la versión de mi navegador, lo copie en la carpeta de windows pensado que ese era el error, pero me sigue saliendo y la verdad no se que mas hacer para que me pueda ejecutar la llamada al navegador y cargue la pagina que le envió.
EL código que uso es este.

```
Sub ConsultarRunt()
  Dim bot As New ChromeDriver
  bot.Get "https://www.runt.com.co/consultaCiudadana/#/consultaPersona"
End Sub
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución a mi problema fue muy sencilla, lo que hice fue poner en la carpeta donde tenia selenium instalado el chromedriver y lo remplace por el que venia en el paquete y mi problema quedo resuelto